# Google Analytics not working in Webview in iOS app

Tags: javascript, ios, google-analytics

Let me first start out by saying I know how to use the iOS SDK so please don't answer this with a "just use the SDK." I want to know WHY google analytics is not working.

Here's my setup. I have a web app that is also baked into an android app and ios app via webview. I'm using cordova. The android app works just fine with the GA JS code. The web works just fine. However no events or page views are showing up from iOS. I've heard that GA is tied to the domain so does an iOS Webview do something under the hood to the domain?

I was going to attach my code snippet but it's coffeescript in a few classes so I'll just paste the compiled js

```
  Analytics.prototype.track = function(args) {
      window._gaq.push(args);
  };
  Analytics.track(['_trackEvent', 'SubscriptionModal', "Closed", data]);
```

This works fine in web and android so it's not a JS. I'm setting the GA _setDomainName to 'focusatwill.com' and can see that both ios and web have a domain of 'www.focusatwill.com'

I've read online a few people talking about this issue and everyone says just use the SDK. I'm looking for the reason why it doesn't work. How do you fix it to use the JS?

**edit**

I should mention that the html and JS are not baked into the device, ie they don't have a local url but are served up from our webserver

Comment: For your GA app, do you have the project set up as a mobile app? I've ran into this project in a similar manner, and I ultimately ended up setting up two projects under the GA account; 1 for the mobile site (for webview clicks) and another for the actual app to log events within the app itself (non-webview)

Comment: It's a web tracker. Android works with web tracks but seems like iOS uiwebviews don't and I curious why? Is it due to not being able to save the GA image file locally? Or some other cookie issue? Just curious if anyone actually knows why

Comment: `track` is a prototype method, but you're calling the object method..

Answer (score 0):

Safari on iOS6+ blocks third party cookies by default, and I'm certain that webviews do too.

Check that you have something similar to the following in the init method of AppDelegate.m:

```
NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookieStorage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
[cookieStorage setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways];
```

That's from the standard boilerplate generated by Cordova 3.0.9, but might not be present if you're using a version that predates iOS6. It sets the app-specific cookie policy, which should override the system default.